# Expressjs change context where the server executes the app from

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs

I'd like to know if it's possible to change the context from where the Express server is serving from, to avoid issues in the import/require files in the App that is served.

I'm serving from [root]/server.js, this file checks for the process.env.NODE_ENV and then requires a file in let's say `./dist/ENVIRONMENT/server.js`

```
if (['staging', 'production'].indexOf(process.env.NODE_ENV) > -1) {
  require('./dist/' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '/server.js')
} else {
  require('babel-register')
  require('./server.dev.js')
}
```

The files that are served are triggering an error related with the import/require locations that fails for the reason explained in the previous paragraph

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../../../xxxxx'
```

Why am I doing this? I'm transpiling the server source code for non development (that runs with babel) and then copied to the distribution directory. I understand that I can have tasks to rename and move this accordingly during deployment, that also solves the problem, but I'd like to learn or understand if we're able to change the context where the Express server, serves from!

From the top of my head, I guess I'll have to solve it through something like (which I'll be testing):

```
var dist = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../')
app.use(express.static(dist))
```

Which I attempted, but failed, same error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../../../../config'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxx/www/projectFoobar/dist/staging/lib/services/foobarService/index.js:13:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

The config file happens to be in the [root] directory.

** OK just realised that using import/export is a bad practice

https://nodesource.com/blog/es-modules-and-node-js-hard-choices/